# Sitecore 7 Analytics increase engagement value programatically

Tags: sitecore, analytics, sitecore7, sitecore-dms, sitecore7.2

I am working on implementing sitecore DMS in 7.2 and I'm having one main issue for which I seem to be having a hard time finding an answer. I have some goals and events set up and I am attempting to set one off through the Analytics API. The event is being logged as being set off in the PageEventId database, but what I am trying to do is add Engagement Value to the current visit/visitor.

I'm looking to update the Value field in the Visits database for the current visit. Here is what I am currently using:

```
public static void triggerGoal(ID goal)
{
    if (Tracker.IsActive && Tracker.CurrentPage != null)
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item goalToTrigger = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(goal);
        if (goalToTrigger != null)
        {
            Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.PageEventItem reg = new Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.PageEventItem(goalToTrigger);
            Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataSets.VisitorDataSet.PageEventsRow eventData = 

            Tracker.CurrentPage.Register(reg);
            eventData.Data = goalToTrigger["Description"];
            Tracker.Submit();
        }
    }
}
```

This updates the PageEventId database properly, noting that the event has been triggered, but this adds no Engagement Value to the Visits database, regardless of how many engagement points are assigned to the Goad that is being triggered.

I've tried various ways of getting the API to update this field, but nothing has worked for me so far. Here are a bunch of the different things I've tried:

```
Tracker.CurrentVisit.BeginEdit();
Tracker.CurrentVisit.Value += 3; //look up value here instead of hardcoding. Create new PageEventItem class to get field ID.
Tracker.CurrentVisit.AcceptChanges();
Tracker.CurrentVisit.EndEdit();
Tracker.CurrentVisit.Load();
Tracker.CurrentPage.BeginEdit();
Tracker.CurrentPage.Visit.Value += 3;
Tracker.CurrentPage.AcceptChanges();
Tracker.CurrentPage.EndEdit();
Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.BeginEdit();
Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.Value += 3;
Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.AcceptChanges();
Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.EndEdit();
Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.Load();
Tracker.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage.Visit.BeginEdit();
Tracker.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage.Visit.Value += 3;
Tracker.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage.Visit.AcceptChanges();
Tracker.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage.Visit.EndEdit();
Tracker.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage.Visit.Load();
Tracker.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage.VisitorsRow.BeginEdit();
Tracker.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage.VisitorsRow.Value += 3;
Tracker.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage.VisitorsRow.AcceptChanges();
Tracker.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage.VisitorsRow.EndEdit();
```

I've used different combinations of using the AcceptChanges() and BeginEdit() EndEdit() and Load() functions, as I'm not completely sure what they each do, but either way, none of them update the Value field.

I am trying to avoid doing a custom SQL query to update this field, I'm trying to figure out how to do it through the built-in Sitecore Analytics API. Can anyone help me figure out how to update this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine for me, are you waiting long enough to see the value written for the visit?

```
if (Tracker.IsActive)
{
    Tracker.CurrentVisit.Value += 3;
}
```

No need to BeginEdit, AcceptChanges, EndEdit, etc.

Comment: Okay, so I think I may have found the issue, which was something totally separate and underlying the Tracker code, but now that the initial issue was resolved, this here code does, in fact, work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What you've done should work so long as you have set up your goal correctly in Sitecore. I like to mirror sitecore's default goals, and create goals of the "Page Event" template. Make sure that you've assigned the goal to your content item `Analyze Tab -> Goals -> [select your goal from checkbox list]`. If you're going to set the CurrentVisit value, I suggest using the line below to prevent hardcoding the engagement point values.

```
//This line will add points specified in Content Editor
Tracker.CurrentVisit.Value += int.Parse(reg.Points);
```

This document explains how to set up your goals the correct way. And if you follow it, your code will work the way you have it, reporting the value specified in the Content Editor without setting CurrentVisit.Value.
[Sitecore SDN - Marketing Operations Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/72/marketing_operations_cookbook_sc72-a4.pdf)